# Why I shouldn't fluxing everything?

Tags: reactjs-flux, flux, redux

Several months ago I met a flux and I found it's awesome, I love it, I use it.. almost in every new project and when I met a redux I love it even more, but couple of days ago Pete Hunt publish a [tweet](https://twitter.com/floydophone/status/649786438330945536) where he judge the people to use flux for everything. And I think it have a perfect sense, but on the other hand I don't get it.. He publish another [tweet](https://twitter.com/floydophone/status/649835101631574016) where explain cases for flux, also I read [an article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/the-case-for-flux-379b7d1982c6) about use cases for flux. Long story short - "If your app doesn’t have complex data changes and caching, don’t use it. But if it does, I strongly recommend you try Flux." and it's totally make sense for me why I should use flux, but it not clear to me why I shouldn't if I don't have a complex data changes.

In the article Dan point, that when you faced those issues(that flux solve) in real project you can easier to understands the benefits of the flux, but exactly of this(cause I faced with these problems at work project) now I try to use flux in every project, because I don't wanna to deal with it anymore.

And crazy part, that now I often use it also for ui states, not just data changes. Let's pretend I can have a widget component, for example a clock. It can make some ui changes, like show/hide seconds, switch between digital/analog and it has a daytime type state(day/night) and can dispatch an event when it changed, but other component listen it and can react, for example change a background color. I can easily solve it just with local component state and container(smart component) state, but same as I can put all these logic into store(reducers) and components will be really dump and just react on the current state(props) and containers(smart) just listen the store and partitioned state between the components. And if even it looks ok, point that I can use it for every ui state - open/close sidebar, some specific component changes, etc.

Reasons why I can do it:

- It looks predictable for me. I completely know that any changes happened in my app serve in one place.
- It easy to debug. I can just log all the actions and if I will get some bug, I can easily found what happened and reproduce it.
- I can easily expand my app without worrying, mb I should move something to the flux state, cause I already did it.

But also I agree that it's looks overwhelmed and I can solve it without flux, but I can't answer to me, why I shouldn't use flux in these cases. What is wrong with it? Please help me.